# "haven't received permission from the user to play sounds" for ios devices

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, server-push

When a server notification pushed in my app, my device is not playing sound. I have searched a lot and I tried all of the recommanded solutions, but I couldn't solve the problem. Still, it gives the error which is written for question's title.

**Here is my code:**

```
// Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
if (application.respondsToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))) {
   var userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = (.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
   var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
   application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
   application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
else
{
   // Register for Push Notifications earlier from iOS 8
   application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound)
}
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you for your answers,

Best regards

**Note:** I have debugged the "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method and notification sound already came as "default".

Comment: Have you previously requested different permissions or denied permissions?  Try deleting the app from your device/simulator and reinstalling it.

Comment: I tried it again, but still the same @Paulw11

Comment: Do you actually get the permissions prompt?  Have you set a breakpoint to confirm that your request code is actually executed?

Comment: No, I am not getting that prompt. I recently realized it. But I received that prompt earlier. @Paulw11

Comment: When I run application on similator, it shows me that prompt, but when I run on my device, it does not show me ? @Paulw11